# What's the probability of either $k$ or more successes or $k$ or more failures in $k \leq n \leq 2k$ trials.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say the probability of success is $p$.

I found a way to express it as a sum by looking at the converse. Letting $n=k+l$ where $l<k$, we can compute

$$P(x)= 1-\sum _{j=l+1}^{k-1} \binom{k+l}{j} p^j (1-p)^{-j+k+l}$$

by summing over all of the possible ways to not get either. However, I couldn't find a way to simplify this sum further.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why is the answer to the question in your title not: $\sum\limits_{n=k}^{2k} \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expression in the form which does not require an additional parameter:

$$P(x)=1-\sum_{j=n-k+1}^{k-1}\binom nj p^j(1-p)^{n-j}.$$

Observe that already for $n=2k-1$ it is impossible that neither successes nor failures happen $k$ or more times.

Above I assumed that both $n$ and $k$ are fixed.